# Rails, Unexpected nil error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, each

I'm fairly new to rails and I'm working on an app that displays "offerings" in the index view based upon whether they are active, have sufficient inventory, and whether the pickup_location for the offering is near the current_user's "location".

The below setup worked for several days and suddenly started throwing a no method error.  I've been stumped on this for several days now. I would really appreciate any advice on how to work through this and what may have caused this error to suddenly appear.

index.html.erb

```
<% if current_or_guest_user.location.any? && @offerings.any? %>
  <div class="current-location">
    <h2>Offerings Near <%= current_or_guest_user.location.last.locationString %></h2>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <% @offerings.each do |offering| %>
        <%= render "offering_row", offering: offering, order_item: @order_item %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

/offerings.controller.rb

```
def index

  if current_or_guest_user.location.any?
    @cooks = PickupLocation.near(current_or_guest_user.location.last.coordinates).collect { |location| location.user }

    offerings = []

    @cooks.each do |cook|
      cook.offerings.active.inventory.each do |offering|
        offerings.push(offering)
      end
    end

    @offerings = offerings
  end

  @order_item = current_order.order_items.new
end
```

Error output

```
Started GET "/" for ::1 at 2015-09-19 12:51:54 -0700
Processing by OfferingsController#index as HTML
User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 63]]
Location Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "locations" WHERE "locations"."user_id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 63]]
Location Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "locations".* FROM "locations" WHERE "locations"."user_id" = $1  ORDER BY "locations"."id" DESC LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 63]]
PickupLocation Load (1.2ms)  SELECT pickup_locations.*, 3958.755864232 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((33.4484911 - pickup_locations.latitude) * PI() / 180 / 2), 2) + COS(33.4484911 * PI() / 180) * COS(pickup_locations.latitude * PI() / 180) * POWER(SIN((-112.0744277 - pickup_locations.longitude) * PI() / 180 / 2), 2))) AS distance, MOD(CAST((ATAN2( ((pickup_locations.longitude - -112.0744277) / 57.2957795), ((pickup_locations.latitude - 33.4484911) / 57.2957795)) * 57.2957795) + 360 AS decimal), 360) AS bearing FROM "pickup_locations" WHERE (pickup_locations.latitude BETWEEN 33.1590275337783 AND 33.7379546662217 AND pickup_locations.longitude BETWEEN -112.42134755027531 AND -111.72750784972469 AND (3958.755864232 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((33.4484911 - pickup_locations.latitude) * PI() / 180 / 2), 2) + COS(33.4484911 * PI() / 180) * COS(pickup_locations.latitude * PI() / 180) * POWER(SIN((-112.0744277 - pickup_locations.longitude) * PI() / 180 / 2), 2)))) BETWEEN 0.0 AND 20)  ORDER BY distance ASC
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 63]]


CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 63]]
User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 120]]
User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 130]]
User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 136]]
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 136]]
User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 142]]
User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 144]]
User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 106]]
User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 146]]
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 106]]
Offering Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "offerings".* FROM "offerings" WHERE "offerings"."user_id" = $1 AND "offerings"."active" = 't' AND (quantity > 0)  [["user_id", 63]]
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "offerings".* FROM "offerings" WHERE "offerings"."user_id" = $1 AND "offerings"."active" = 't' AND (quantity > 0)  [["user_id", 63]]
Offering Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "offerings".* FROM "offerings" WHERE "offerings"."user_id" = $1 AND "offerings"."active" = 't' AND (quantity > 0)  [["user_id", 120]]
Offering Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "offerings".* FROM "offerings" WHERE "offerings"."user_id" = $1 AND "offerings"."active" = 't' AND (quantity > 0)  [["user_id", 130]]
Offering Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "offerings".* FROM "offerings" WHERE "offerings"."user_id" = $1 AND "offerings"."active" = 't' AND (quantity > 0)  [["user_id", 136]]
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "offerings".* FROM "offerings" WHERE "offerings"."user_id" = $1 AND "offerings"."active" = 't' AND (quantity > 0)  [["user_id", 136]]
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 34ms (ActiveRecord: 3.9ms)

NoMethodError (undefined method `offerings' for nil:NilClass):
  app/controllers/offerings_controller.rb:34:in `block in index'
  app/controllers/offerings_controller.rb:33:in `each'
  app/controllers/offerings_controller.rb:33:in `index'
```

Comment: Can you trim down the code?

Comment: The error says that the problem occurs in the `offerings_controller.rb`, so please include this file and remove all other files.

Comment: So your @cooks array is coming up empty. Find out why. Did you reset your DB and forget to re-seed? Did the data change so that nothing met the criteria for your AR Query to populate @cooks?

Comment: @MarsAtomic, I haven't reset the database and if I inspect the array in the view, it returns [#<User id: 63, email: "test1@example.com", encrypted_password: ........>] as expected.

Comment: @EvanCarslake, I've removed the code from the related models.

Comment: Maybe it's not cooks, but offerings that's empty. It would help if you pointed out the lines where the error occurs, since we can't see your text editor. Dump that and see what you get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you're doing a collect here:

```
@cooks = PickupLocation.near(current_or_guest_user.location.last.coordinates).collect { |location| location.user }
```

`location.user` could return a nil which will throw the error you got.

You may want to either:

- Remove nils from the collect (e.g. `@cooks.compact`)
- Have validations that ensure you have a user associated to a location when you save

Comment: Thank you!  Your .compact suggestion worked and will also add the validations you suggest.